# TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined - React-redux-firebase, Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

I have been developing a project where the user can change password. I want to reauthenticate the current user using

```
currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(
            firebase
              .auth()
              .EmailAuthProvider.credential(
                currentUser.email,
                credentials.userOldPassword
              )
          )
          .then(() => console.log("authenticated"))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But it gives an error like

> Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined

I am using react-redux-firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EmailProvider` class is in the `auth` **namespace**, not in the `auth` instance. So the correct syntax is:

```
firebase
  .auth // no parenthesis here
  .EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    currentUser.email,
    credentials.userOldPassword
  )
```

Also see the Firebase documentation for the [`EmailAuthProvider.credential` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#static-credential).