# How to reauthenticate with @nativescript/firebase-auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I want to force a user to reenter its password on a security sensitive step in my app.

I want to use reauthenticateWithCredential but no documentation seems to fit my case using @nativescript/firebase-auth since EmailAuthProvider is always undefined.

This is a similar issue for react.

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined - React-redux-firebase, Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956051/typeerror-cannot-read-property-credential-of-undefined-react-redux-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

I found the proper sequence to retrieve the user and inject the credential object.
There was also a little catch where reauthenticateWithCredential is coming directly from the user.

```
import '@nativescript/firebase-auth';
import { EmailAuthProvider } from '@nativescript/firebase-auth';

const user = firebase().auth().currentUser;
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, password);

try {
  await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
  //Good password
}catch(e){
  //Wrong password
}
```

Hope it may be of help to anyone.